Delete polygon not remove polygons from drawing manager
I am working with google maps.where i have to add polygons and delete polygons as well.code
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, DrawingManager, Polygon } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100vh',
};

const center = {
  lat: 0,
  lng: 0,
};

const DrawPolygonMap = () => {
  const [drawingMode, setDrawingMode] = useState(false);
  const [drawnShapes, setDrawnShapes] = useState([]);
  const [drawingManager, setDrawingManager] = useState(null);

  // Callback when DrawingManager initializes
  const onLoadDrawingManager = useCallback((drawingManager) => {
    setDrawingManager(drawingManager);
  }, []);

  // Callback when a polygon is complete
  const onPolygonComplete = useCallback((polygon) => {
    setDrawnShapes((prevShapes) => [...prevShapes, polygon]);
  }, []);

  // Toggle drawing mode
  const toggleDrawingMode = () => {
    setDrawingMode((prevMode) => {
      if (!prevMode && drawingManager) {
        // Clear existing shapes when starting drawing mode
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); // Clear any existing drawing mode
        setDrawnShapes([]); // Clear drawn shapes
      }
      return !prevMode;
    });
  };

  // Delete all drawn shapes
  const deleteShapes = () => {
    setDrawnShapes([]);
  };

  return (
    <LoadScript
      googleMapsApiKey="key" // Replace with your actual API key
      libraries={['drawing']}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        center={center}
        zoom={10}
      >
        {drawingMode && (
          <DrawingManager
            onLoad={onLoadDrawingManager}
            onPolygonComplete={onPolygonComplete}
            options={{
              drawingControl: true,
              drawingControlOptions: {
                drawingModes: ['polygon'],
              },
              polygonOptions: {
                editable: true,
                draggable: true,
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
        {drawnShapes.map((shape, index) => (
          <Polygon
            key={index}
            paths={shape?.getPath()?.getArray()}
            options={{
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              fillColor: '#FF0000',
              fillOpacity: 0.35,
              editable: true,
              draggable: true,
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>

      <div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 10, left: 10 }}>
        <button onClick={toggleDrawingMode}>
          {drawingMode ? 'Stop Drawing' : 'Start Drawing'}
        </button>
        <button onClick={deleteShapes} disabled={drawnShapes.length === 0}>
          Delete Shapes
        </button>
      </div>
    </LoadScript>
  );
};

export default DrawPolygonMap;

now i can add polygons. But delete polygons not working.i could update  drawnShapes to initial state. But still i can see polygons there in map.so its coming internally? Any help from highly appreciated. Thanks in advance
